# putting .htm at the end of url with .htaccess in OSCLASS scripts

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo, osclass

I am using OSCLASS script and I am using .htaccess to rewrite the urls. The default .htaccess that OSCLASS makes, gives urls like this ( http://myhost.com/saleon/vehicles/cars/honda-civic_i28 ) I want to add '.htm' at the end of each url. So that my url would look something like this ( http://myhost.com/saleon/vehicles/cars/honda-civic_i28.htm ). Does anyone has a clue how to do that in htaccess. My .htaccess code is as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /saleon/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /saleon/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do that in the `.htaccess`. You can change that in the oc-admin: `Settings > Permalinks` and then click on `Show rules`.

For example, the default permalink for the listing looks like this: `{ITEM_TITLE}-i{ITEM_ID}` and it generates the url as you mentioned before. However, if you change that value for the following one you will obtain an url ending with .htm: `{ITEM_TITLE}-i{ITEM_ID}.htm`.